# Firebase Android Studio coudn't find com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I face this problem and couldn't solve it. Any help is appreciated.

I tried many solutions and none worked. :(

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            :MyApp:unspecified

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }



}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please show your build.gradle

Comment: you can check the question again man i made eidt for  it

Comment: make sure your google play service is uptodate in sdk manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put it like this in your project gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: OP's build.gradle looks exactly like this

Comment: i removed
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

Comment: @Héctor the question was edited after I posted my answer