# How do I resolve the error Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on the project with Firebase Cloud Messaging, following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and I'm getting the error below every time I run the program. Please I need help.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'e'.
>        Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>           Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0:.
>            Searched in the following locations:
>                file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom
>                file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.jar
>                https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom
>                https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.jar
>                file:/C:/Users/e/.m2/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.pom
>                file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0//3.0.0-.jar
>            Required by:
>                project :

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40018916/4815718.  Make sure you have `jcenter()` in the repositories list of your project build.gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Android Studio coudn't find com.google.gsm:google-services:3.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018916/firebase-android-studio-coudnt-find-com-google-gsmgoogle-services3-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```